# How does the mass of a black hole varies?

Tags: black-holes

Is there any change of the mass of a black hole if time passes ? As it absorb any mass near it, will the mass of the black hole gets increased, or as it radiates energy, will the mass of it gets decreased ?

Comment: Such information is easily found on the internet.  The policy of this website is that you are expected to make an effort to do your own research.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any change of the mass of a black hole if time passes ?

The present day thinking is that largest black holes are in existence located at the center of galaxies, and may have masses equivalent to about a billion suns.

According to General Theory of Relativity  there is no lower limit to the size of a black hole.

As black holes eats up "materials" so the change in mass is imminent.

Its a misnomer that black holes radiate energy and thus it may reduce its mass.

> In the quasar situation , a super massive black hole (a billion solar masses or so) lies at the center of a galaxy, and gas near the black hole forms an accretion disk around the hole;  X-rays, and other forms of light, are the radiation being emitted from the disc..

In none of these cases is light being emitted, and reaching us, from beneath the black hole's event horizon. Nothing can escape from beneath the event horizon.

> Astronomers have found a half-dozen or so binary star systems (two stars orbiting each other) where one of the stars is invisible, yet must be there since it pulls with enough gravitational force on the other visible star to make that star orbit around their common center of gravity  and  the mass of the invisible star is considerably greater than 3 to 5 solar masses. Therefore these invisible stars are thought to be good candidate black holes.

The  explanations of the output of energy by quasars  using a super massive black hole.

*When matter falls in a gravitational field, its speed and therefore energy, increases. If lots of matter is falling in at the same time, and swirling around the black hole in a disk , then friction between the various pieces of matter will turn much of energy picked up during the fall into heat, which than gets radiated away.*

In this way, the matter surrounding a super massive black hole can radiate a lot of energy.

As large amounts of material approach a black hole, the material will generally find itself in an orbiting disk-like structure with the hole at the center .

*This is what gives rise to the extreme brightness of quasars, and this process is what makes us able to (possibly) find stellar-mass black holes that are part of a double star system.*

> Reference: [http://www.phys.vt.edu/~jhs/faq/blackholes.html#q8](http://www.phys.vt.edu/%7Ejhs/faq/blackholes.html#q8)